# Double If statement in windows Batch

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, input

I'll start with the code:

```
@echo off
set number=0

echo What would you like to add to %number%
echo 1. Add nothing
echo 2. Add 1
echo 3. Add number of your choosing

set /p test=

:: doesn't add any number
if "%test%" == "1" (
    echo You have choosen to not add anything
    pause
    goto end
)

::Adds number 1 to 0
if "%test%" == "2" (
    set /a number=number+1
    echo You have added 1 to the number
    goto end
)


::Gives choice to add 2 or 3 to number 0
if "%test%" == "3" (
    echo Which number would you like to add
    echo 1. Number 2
    echo 2. Number 3

    set /p option=

    ::Adds 2 to 0
    if "!option!" == "1"(
        echo You have added 2 to the number
        set /a number=number+2
        pause
    )

    ::Adds 3 to 0
    if "!option!" == "2"(
        echo You have added 3 to the number
        set /a number=number+3
        pause
    )
    goto end
)

:end
echo Your number is %number%
pause
```

This states the number as 0, and then gives you an option to add 0, 1, 2 or 3 to the number 0.
I've done it this way so I can test out having an If statements inside of an if statement that asks for an input but I'm lost.

Adding 0 or 1 to *number* works fine, but as soon as you choose option 3 (wanting to add 2 or 3) it crashes.

I get the error:
The syntax of the command is incorrect

I'm guessing it's a silly mistake, if you could point it out, that would be perfect.

Comment: Stop using `Set /P` for requesting known/specific input! Open up a Command Prompt window, enter `choice /?` or `"%__appdir__%choice.exe" /?` and read the usage information for the more appropriate command for the task.

Comment: So as an example would it be `choice /c 123 /m "What do you choose:"` and that would only allow them to enter 1, 2 or 3? And then do an if statement to branch out to the choice they made?

Comment: I usually use `goto` directly instead of an `if` statement.  `choice /c 123` followed by `goto choice%errorlevel%` and appropriate labels `:choice1` etc.

Comment: Watch your spaces. `if "2" == "2"(` compares `"2"` with `"2"(`, which will never be true. (and of course, you need to enable delayed expansion, as @SeñorCMasMas already said)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't turn echo off!  It is hiding important details when writing batch code!

With echo **NOT** turned off, you will immediately see the error:

***The syntax of the command is incorrect.***
`if "!option!" == "1"(`.

Exclamation syntax only works if  [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) is turned on.  Batch has NO IDEAR what to do with `!var!` without it enabled.

Also.. ***be sure*** to do what @Compo suggests above about `choice.exe`.  It will make you a better person and people wont twitch when they see your code.  We waited A LONG time to get it added.  Please use it.